# Generate a set of unit vectors that sum to a given vector

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Consider a given vector in n dimensional space $x_0 \in \mathcal{R}^n$.

How can I generate a random set of $k$ unit vectors $x_1$, $x_2$ ... $x_k$ 
such that $x_0= \sum_{i=1}^{i=k} x_i $

There are no assumptions involved on the structure or distribution of $x_i's$ except they are unit vectors. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** didn't see the condition that these are unit vectors and can't delete on mobile.

This question is under-specified without saying what sort of distribution you want the resulting vectors to have.

One option would be to pick $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ according to some distribution and then let
$$x_n := x_0 - x_1 - \ldots - x_{n-1}.$$

Another would be to pick $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ according to some distribution, then use some procedure to select a matrix $A$ such that

$$A(v_1 + \ldots + v_n) = x_0$$

and finally take $x_i := A v_i$.

The random distribution of the resulting vectors will in both cases depend on all the choices made beforehand.